# Question concerning -ing ending in a sentence.

Tags: grammar

I am trying to understand why there is an -ing ending in amazing when used in a sentence like, "different countries have proven equally amazing".

Is it because amaze is a present participle verb or is it functioning as an adjective and the adverb is modifying the adjective?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: _Amazing_ is an adjective that came historically from a present participle (like _frightening_), just as _amazed_ is an adjective that came historically from a past participle (like _frightened_). Both kinds of adjective are common in English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you inflect a verb so as to make it a participle you are turning it into an adjective—that is what a participle essentially *is.* Sometimes participles even come to be used as nouns (as many adjectives do), and even come full circle to wind up as verbs again, and those verbs in turn get to have participles of their own, like *parenting.* It’s the functional-shift Circle of Life.